# how to use jconsole remote connect to Resin 4

Tags: jconsole, resin

I want to use jconsole remote connect to Resin 4,but it doesn't work when I modify the resin.properties:

```
#Jconsole config
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port : 8080
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl : false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate : false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname : host_ip
```

I think that it's the resin.properties doesn't take effect,but I don't know how to config it now.

Answer (score 0):

From 4.0 it has to be configured in resin.xml, below is the documentation link however, I am still unable to get the jmx port up and running.

http://caucho.com/resin-4.0/admin/resin-admin-console.xtp#JMXConsole

Comment: Try providing a real answer or add this as a comment. It is more of a hint, than something that solves the problem. Also: links may die out, and answers should be usable for users in upcoming future.

Comment: I am hoping that link might help someone.. that is something than just commenting.